# Python regex remove digits except years

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a regex that turns this string:

```
'foo bar 12 3.4 32 1992 112 0433 3312 182470921358 3,412 some text'
```

into this string:

```
'foo bar    1992      some text'
```

That is, I want to remove all digits from a string except those  digits that represent years (1000 - 2999).

I was looking for a regex feature that does something like

```
(<PATTERN1> except <PATTERN2>)
```

I've been able to come up with `<PATTERN1>` and `<PATTERN2>`:

```
<PATTERN1> -> \b[0-9(.,)+]*\b
<PATTERN2> -> \b[12]{1}[0-9]{3}\b
```

In code:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'foo bar 12 3.4 32 1992 112 0433 3312 182470921358 3,412 some text'
>>> re.sub(r'\b[0-9(.,)+]*\b', '', s)
'foo bar          some text'
>>> import re
>>> print re.sub(r'\b[0-9(.,)+]*\b', '', s)
foo bar          some text
>>> re.sub(r'\b[12]{1}[0-9]{3}\b', '', s)
'foo bar 12 3.4 32  112 0433 3312 182470921358 3,412 some text'
```

But i failed to bring them together. Positive lookbehind doesn't do the trick, either.

This:

```
(?<=\b[12]{1}[0-9]{2})[0-9(.,)+]{1}\b
```

matches only the `2` of `1992` instead of `1992` entirely.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use regexes? You could just use `split()` and remove the elements that are numbers outside of the range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this negative lookahead based regex:

```
>>> s = 'foo bar 12 3.4 32 1992 112 0433 3312 182470921358 3,412 some text'
>>> print re.sub(r'\b(?!(\D\S*|[12][0-9]{3})\b)\S+\b', '', s)
'foo bar    1992      some text'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gL2nF3/1)

`(?!(\D\S*|[12][0-9]{3})` will match anything that is starting with a non-digit or a non-year number outside `1000-2999` range.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the following approach and determine if each number falls within the correct range. This would make it easy to modify the number range if required:

```
import re

def year(match):
    try:
        if 1000 <= int(match.group(1)) <= 2999:
            return match.group(1)
    except ValueError, e:
        pass
    return ''


text = 'foo bar 12 3.4 32 1992 112 0433 3312 182470921358 3,412 some text'
print re.sub('([0-9,.]+)', year, text)
```

This would display:

```
foo bar    1992      some text
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s = 'foo bar 12 3.4 32 1992 112 0433 3312 182470921358 3,412 some text'
p = r'((\b[0-9][0-9.,]{0,2}\b)|(\b[0-9][0-9.,]{4,}\b))|(\b[03-9][\d]{3}\b)'
print re.sub(p, '', s)
```

output:

```
'foo bar    1992      some text'
```

Foolish method.